# JS JSON Array Query

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have JSON data that I want to filter that is an array type.

```
{
    "1": {
      "enemy_id": 1,
      "ai_": 0,
      "ailmentcast1": -1
      },
    "9": {
      "enemy_id": 2,
      "ai_": 5,
      "ailmentcast1": 2
      },
    "2": {
      "enemy_id": 4,
      "ai_": 10,
      "ailmentcast1": 7
      },
    "29": {
      "enemy_id": 1,
      "ai_": 1,
      "ailmentcast1": 15
      },
    "17": {
      "enemy_id": 3,
      "ai_": 7,
      "ailmentcast1": 10
      }
}
```

I want to filter out sets with enemy_id != 1. So a return would look like this:

```
{
    "9": {
      "enemy_id": 2,
      "ai_": 5,
      "ailmentcast1": 2
      },
    "2": {
      "enemy_id": 4,
      "ai_": 10,
      "ailmentcast1": 7
      },
    "17": {
      "enemy_id": 3,
      "ai_": 7,
      "ailmentcast1": 10
      }
}
```

I have a functions I have tried but I'm having a hard time with the formatting.

```
function find_in_object(my_object, my_criteria){
  return my_object.filter(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(my_criteria).every(function(c) {
      return obj[c] == my_criteria[c];
    });
  });

}
```

And the code I ran that didn't work:

```
  var newdata = [];
  var filter = JSON.parse(content, function(key, value) { 
      if ( value.enemy_id !== 1 ) newdata.push(value); 
      return value; });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The second argument to `JSON.parse` is a function that can clean up the whole object before it's returned. It looks like here you're presuming it gives you individual values, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using `Object.entries` to turn the object in an array. Now you'll have an array of *key-value* pairs like:

```
[
  "1", // key
  { // value
    "enemy_id": 1,
    "ai_": 0,
    "ailmentcast1": -1
  }
]
```

From here you can access the `enemy_id` property in the value and use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to only return the key-value pairs where the `enemy_id` is a match with the id given.

Then turn the array of *entries* back into an object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). It is basically the reverse of `Object.entries`.

```js
const data = {
  "1": {
    "enemy_id": 1,
    "ai_": 0,
    "ailmentcast1": -1
  },
  "9": {
    "enemy_id": 2,
    "ai_": 5,
    "ailmentcast1": 2
  },
  "2": {
    "enemy_id": 4,
    "ai_": 10,
    "ailmentcast1": 7
  },
  "29": {
    "enemy_id": 1,
    "ai_": 1,
    "ailmentcast1": 15
  },
  "17": {
    "enemy_id": 3,
    "ai_": 7,
    "ailmentcast1": 10
  }
};

const filterEnemyById = (data, id) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).filter(([key, { enemy_id }]) => 
    enemy_id !== id
  )
);

const result = filterEnemyById(data, 1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you for your time 

Answer (score 1):

Try the snippet below. It actually is a one-liner and it changes the keys of the initial object.

```js
let q = {
    "1": {
      "enemy_id": 1,
      "ai_": 0,
      "ailmentcast1": -1
      },
    "9": {
      "enemy_id": 2,
      "ai_": 5,
      "ailmentcast1": 2
      },
    "2": {
      "enemy_id": 4,
      "ai_": 10,
      "ailmentcast1": 7
      },
    "29": {
      "enemy_id": 1,
      "ai_": 1,
      "ailmentcast1": 15
      },
    "17": {
      "enemy_id": 3,
      "ai_": 7,
      "ailmentcast1": 10
      }
};
let output = Object.assign({},Object.values(q).filter(x => x.enemy_id != 1));
console.log(output);
```

Use `Object.values` to turn your object to an `Array`. Then use `Array.filter()` to actually filter out the entries you want. Use `Object.assign()` to keep the `Object` datatype instead of the `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're really close here, where you can define a separate matching function like:

```
function entryMatches(entry, criteria) {
  return Object.keys(criteria).every(k => entry[k] == criteria[k]);
}
```

Then a filtering function that engages that on each key, but still returns the same type of structure:

```
function dataFilter(data, criteria) {
  let result = { };

  Object.keys(data).filter(k => entryMatches(data[k], criteria)).forEach(k => {
    result[k] = data[k];
  });

  return result;
}
```

Where you get results like this:

```js
function entryMatches(entry, criteria) {
  return Object.keys(criteria).every(k => entry[k] == criteria[k]);
}

function dataFilter(data, criteria) {
  let result = { };

  Object.keys(data).filter(k => entryMatches(data[k], criteria)).forEach(k => {
    result[k] = data[k];
  });

  return result;
}

const data = {
  1: {
    enemy_id: 1,
    ai_: 0,
    ailmentcast1: -1
  },
  9: {
    enemy_id: 2,
    ai_: 5,
    ailmentcast1: 2
  },
  2: {
    enemy_id: 4,
    ai_: 10,
    ailmentcast1: 7
  },
  29: {
    enemy_id: 1,
    ai_: 1,
    ailmentcast1: 15
  },
  17: {
    enemy_id: 3,
    ai_: 7,
    ailmentcast1: 10
  }
};

console.log(dataFilter(data, { enemy_id: 1, ailmentcast1: -1 }));
// { '1': { enemy_id: 1, ai_: 0, ailmentcast1: -1 } }

console.log(dataFilter(data, { enemy_id: 2 }));
// { '9': { enemy_id: 2, ai_: 5, ailmentcast1: 2 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object.entries and then reduce to filter out the records

```js
const input = {
  "1": {
    "enemy_id": 1,
    "ai_": 0,
    "ailmentcast1": -1
  },
  "9": {
    "enemy_id": 2,
    "ai_": 5,
    "ailmentcast1": 2
  },
  "2": {
    "enemy_id": 4,
    "ai_": 10,
    "ailmentcast1": 7
  },
  "29": {
    "enemy_id": 1,
    "ai_": 1,
    "ailmentcast1": 15
  },
  "17": {
    "enemy_id": 3,
    "ai_": 7,
    "ailmentcast1": 10
  }
}


const result = Object.entries(input).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  if (val['enemy_id'] !== 1) {
    acc[key] = val;
  }
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for to loop and remove unwanted eles:

> [for ..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in): The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable
> properties of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed
> by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties.

```js
var data = {
    "1": {
        "enemy_id": 1,
        "ai_": 0,
        "ailmentcast1": -1
    },
    "9": {
        "enemy_id": 2,
        "ai_": 5,
        "ailmentcast1": 2
    },
    "2": {
        "enemy_id": 4,
        "ai_": 10,
        "ailmentcast1": 7
    },
    "29": {
        "enemy_id": 1,
        "ai_": 1,
        "ailmentcast1": 15
    },
    "17": {
        "enemy_id": 3,
        "ai_": 7,
        "ailmentcast1": 10
    }
};

for (e in data) {
    if (data[e].enemy_id == 1) {
        delete data[e];
    }
}


console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
const filtered = Object.entries(data).filter(entry => entry[1].enemy_id != 1).reduce((dict, entry) => {
  dict[entry[0]] = entry[1];
  return dict;
}, {});
```

it will return your data in the initial form.

https://jsfiddle.net/ea0zpxkr/